# Best incremental backup solution for Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, backup

What is the best incremental backup solution for Windows 8.1 that can create bootable backups? My main dilemma is having 3TB of data on my main desktop and would like to back up all these SSDs to one 4TB HDD with it partitioned appropriately. I would also like the ability to clone a partition to a new drive should an individual drive fail.

Ideally I would like to have the ability to schedule backups and perhaps even back up to a NAS on the LAN from a laptop using the same software.

Quite a tall order I know, but I'm a Mac refugee that has recently come back over to Windows after being unimpressed with the new Mac Pro's stability and endless issues with the MBP and MBA too.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/en-us/personal/):

- not free
- Windows XP to [8.1](http://www.acronis.com/en-us/pr/2013/10/31-10-02.html)
- incremental and differential backups
- recover the complete system or [individual files](http://www.acronis.com/en-us/resource/solutions/restore/2005/how-to-restore-individual-files.html)
- can create [bootable CD or USB](http://www.whatsabyte.com/P1/Acronis_restore.htm)

[image]

Comment: + Simple operation

Comment: How is "not free" a feature! I LOL'd a bit then.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend Todo Backup

- Even the free version, it is still powerful and reliable
- Support up to 4TB+
- List item
- Full/Incremential/differential/schedule backup
- Disk/Partition clone, migrate to SSD/HDD

For more information, you can find in here:
http://www.todo-backup.com/products/home/comparison.htm